# Associate one and only one object

Tags: java, associations, one-to-one

Hello I have one question.

I have Class A and Class B. I create one object A and multiple objects B. But I want only one B can set with A.
e.x

```
class A{} 
class B{ private A a;}
public static void main(String[] args){
     A a= new A();
     B b= new B();
     B c= new B();
     b.setA(a);
     c.setA(a);//Sould not assign it.
}
```

Comment: Can you explain  *'I want only one B can set with A'* more clearly?

Comment: @AKSingh better one A have only one B. Because one b can set with A for b.set(a) and c.set(a). Both have set one A.

Comment: You can not do that in Java.  You are creating an Object of the (Class blueprint B), which allows using .setA().  

If you create an instance of new B(), it will always be able to say .setA()

Comment: @SusanMustafa exactly and how can do this is database job to return an error? e.x JPA can make checks?

Comment: You need to show more code @george of what/how exactly you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to implement such a concept.

---

## Code

```
class A {}

public class B
{
    private static final HashSet<A> setA = new HashSet<>();
    private A a;

    public void setA(A a)
    {
        if (!setA.contains(a))
        {
            this.a = a;
            setA.add(a);
        }
    }

    public A getA() { return a; }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a0 = new A();
        A a1 = new A();

        B b0 = new B();
        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = new B();

        b0.setA(a0);
        b1.setA(a1);
        // Below two operations fail silently
        b2.setA(a0);
        b2.setA(a1);

        System.out.println(b0.getA());
        System.out.println(b1.getA());
        System.out.println(b2.getA());
    }
}
```

*You can even throw a custom exception instead of failing silently.*

---

## Output

```
george_17092021_1434.A@568db2f2
george_17092021_1434.A@378bf509
null
```

---

## Conclusion

Doing so should help in achieving what you want. However, I do not know if this is something to be used professionally or not. Please comment if you face any problems.

Comment: thanks for your  comment 
`class B{
    private static List<A> hasA= new ArrayList<>();
    private A a;

    public void setA(A a){
        if(!hasA.contains(a)){
            this.a=a;
            this.hasA.add(a);
        }
    }`

Comment: I suggest using `HashSet`. It offers constant-time performance when you use add, remove and contains operation. I have updated my answer.

Comment: why HashSet is better than List? I mean how come up with that result without search google.

Comment: *Add, remove and contains operation are really fast in `HashSet` in comparison with  `ArrayList`*. In the provided code, *contains* and *add* operation will be used a lot and hence HashSet in a better choice. I have already worked with both of them. Therefore, I knew about it without any google search :)